# Vectorize kroniker multiplcation with trace calculations

Tags: matlab, vectorization, trace

Repost with additional details that greatly change the scope of my first question. Here is the original code:

```
K = zeros(N*N)
for a=1:N
    for i=1:I
        for j=1:J
            M = kron(X(:,:,a).',Y(:,:,a,i,j));

            pr = real(trace(E*M));
            K = K+H(i,j,a)*M/pr;
        end
    end
end
```

Where E is a boolean mask, H is 3D matrix containing N IxJ histograms. K is the output

The goal is to vectorize the kroniker multiplication calls. My intuition is to think of X and Y as containers of matrices (for reference, the slices of X and Y being fed to kron are square matrices of the order 7x7). Under this container scheme, X appears a 1-D container and Y as a 3-D container. My next guess was to reshape Y into a 2-D container or better yet a 1-D container and then do element wise multiplication of X and Y. Questions are: how would do this reshaping in a way that preserves the trace of M and can matlab even handle this idea in this container idea or do the containers need to be further reshaped to expose the inner matrix elements further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matrix multiplication with `7D` permute**

```
% Get sizes
[m1,m2,~] =  size(X);
[n1,n2,N,n4,n5] =  size(Y);

% Perform kron format elementwise multiplication betwen the first two dims
% of X and Y, keeping the third dim aligned and "pushing out" leftover dims
% from Y to the back
mults = bsxfun(@times,permute(X,[4,2,5,1,3]),permute(Y,[1,6,2,7,3,4,5]));
mults3D = reshape(mults,m1*n1,m2*n2,[]);
Emults3D = reshape(E*reshape(mults3D,size(mults3D,1),[]),size(mults3D));

% Trace summations by using linear indices of diagonal on 3D slices in Emults3D
MN = m1*n1;
idx = 1:MN+1:MN^2;
idx2D = bsxfun(@plus,idx(:),MN^2*(0:size(Emults3D,3)-1));
pr_sums = sum(Emults3D(idx2D),1);

% Perform "M/pr" equivalent elementwise divisions and then use
% matrix-multiplication to reduce the iterative summations
Mp = bsxfun(@rdivide,mults3D,reshape(pr_sums,1,1,[]));
out = reshape(Mp,[],size(Mp,3))*reshape(permute(H,[3,1,2]),[],1);
out = reshape(out,m1*n1,m2*n2);
```

---

**Benchmarking**

The inputs were setup like so -

```
% Size parameter
n = 5;

% Setup inputs
X = rand(n,n,n);
Y = rand(n,n,n,n,n);
E = rand(n*n,n*n)>0.5;
H = rand(n,n,n);
num_iter = 500; % Number of iterations to run the approaches for
```

The runtime results were -

```
----------------------------- With Loop
Elapsed time is 8.806286 seconds.
----------------------------- With Vectorization
Elapsed time is 1.471877 seconds.
```

With the size parameter `n` set as `10`, the runtimes were -

```
----------------------------- With Loop
Elapsed time is 5.068872 seconds.
----------------------------- With Vectorization
Elapsed time is 4.399783 seconds.
```

Comment: Been playing around with your solution within my actual project and it only offers a speedup of about 15%. The majority of the time (51%) is spent on the line `Emults3D = reshape(E*reshape(mults3D,size(mults3D,1),[]),size(mults3D));` Is there anyway to better optimize this? What exactly about this line is all that slow: the multiplication by E or reshaping such a large object (81x81x17600 in my specific application) twice?

Comment: @MikeVandenberg I would blame the large size of inputs and the memory bandwidth again specifically on creating that huge `Emults3D`. I am afraid for such huge datasets, we have hit the performance limit there.

Comment: Would there be any advantage in attempting to rewrite this in a lower level language to optimize memory allocation and movements? If E were a very simply mask (such as an identity matrix), are there any "shortcuts" that would avoid the multiple reshapes or simplify extracting the traces?

Comment: @MikeVandenberg Could be! Alternatively, if you could get your hands on a GPU, could be worth porting it over to gpuarrays : http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html

Comment: Does the GPU have to be nvidia for cuda acceleration?

Comment: @MikeVandenberg I am not sure, check up on the MATLAB docs for it.